# Want to register my SIP_Server

Tags: netbeans, cisco, sip-server

I want to create sip servlet on netbeans/Tomcat, my purpose is to register with Cisco Call Manager Server with ip [192.168.2.2],

I tried multiple servlets but actually i donot know how to run my servlet in netbeans,

Answer (score 0):

Please Check out Mobicents SIP Servlets http://dzone.com/links/mobicents_sip_servlets_200final_with_support_for.html

We don't have netbeans integration but we have Eclipse.